# Concate List Item value

Tags: c#, linq, foreach

```
StrManagers = string.Empty;

foreach (Manager manager in Managers)
{
 StrManagers = manager.Name + "</br>";
}
```

How can I achieve this using Linq?

Comment: Not a 100% duplicate, but you can use `Managers.Select(m => m.Name)` to get the string property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `String.Join` method:

```
String.Join("</br>", Managers.Select(manager => manager.Name));
```

Comment: Doesn't it join Manager instead of Manager.name?

Comment: This will join the names of the managers. Actually, this `Managers.Select(manager => manager.Name)` defines a sequence of the manager names.